# Como capturar o evento de clique com o scroll do mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento, click, mouse

Minha dúvida é 'simples', mas não encontro resposta 'definitiva' em lugar nenhum:

É possível capturar especificamente o clique do scroll do mouse com JS?

Existe a função `.click()`, que eu utilizo bastante, mas há como saber qual parte do mouse acionou o evento?

O meu problema é que estou efetuando uma validação para abrir um link em nova guia, já efetuei a validação de `ctrlKey`, e preciso encontrar uma solução para validar se o clique foi com o botão esquerdo (padrão) ou se foi com o scroll, pois o mesmo, por padrão, abre uma nova guia.

Answer (score 4):

Faz uma `function` com `mouseup` (quando libera um botão do mouse), que ao soltar qualquer botão do mouse ele captura o `button` que foi solto.

- 0: Botão principal pressionado, geralmente o botão esquerdo ou o
  estado não inicializado
- 1: Botão auxiliar pressionado, geralmente o
  botão de roda ou o botão do meio (se houver)
- 2: Botão secundário
  pressionado, geralmente o botão direito
- 3: Quarto botão, normalmente
  o botão Voltar do navegador
- 4: Quinto botão, normalmente o botão
  Avançar do navegador

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se for `== 1` (botão do scroll que foi solto) basta fazer o que você quer:

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(event){
     alert(event.button)
    if (event.button == 1) {
        //Fazer alguma coisa...
    }
})
```

```html
<h2>Clique aqui em qualquer lugar </h2>
```

Comment: Perfeito jovem. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @DiegoFagundes, se esta resposta solucionou o seu problema, você pode marcá-la como aceita clicando no botão de _check_ que se encontra no canto superior esquerdo da resposta. :)